# What is the Couchbase XDCR replication order

Tags: couchbase, xdcr

What is the order couchbase replicates data to other cluster, ex: if i configure the XDCR with already existing data in couchbase, 
1. will xdcr pulls data from disk to ram and put it to replication queue
2. will xdcr replication maintains order of documents inserted to couchbase

Comment: I'm looking through the docs, and I don't see anything about ordering, so the behavior may be undefined. I'm curious why it matters for your use case.

Comment: Couchbase has no notion of order of insertion.

Comment: We would like to know the replication status like how much time took for documents transfer between clusters if it has maintained order of inserts.